# Is it possible to share scripts between install4j files?

Tags: install4j

If I have two different install4j files that need the same complex script, is there any way to share that script between the two files or is copy-and-paste duplication the only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use merged projects for reusing screens and actions and their configured scripts.

Under General Settings->Merged Projects add a project that has a "Run script" action with the script in it. Then you can add a link to that action under Installer->Screens & Actions.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try tomorrow.

Comment: Is this a feature that was added in v5.0.x? Sadly, I'm still on v4.2.8 and see no sign of "Merged Projects" under General Settings. :(

Comment: Ah, yes, I see it was - http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/whatsnew5.html